# Windows phone 8 published app. The database file cannot be found. check the path to the database

Tags: windows-phone-8, sql-server-ce

Here is db initialization code:

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext("Data Source=isostore:/my_db.sdf"))
{
   if (!db.DatabaseExists())
   {
      db.CreateDatabase();
   }
}
```

Code works great on debug version, but after publish to the windows phone store it fails.

StackTrace:

```
The database file cannot be found. check the path to the database. [ Data Source = C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData\{A1F26781-AA93-432A-AD80-B02825C3BBA8}\Local\my_db.sdf ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult, Boolean isCompiledQuery)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Boolean isCompiledQuery)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at MyApp.Models.SomeModel.restoreObjectData()
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the database to the isostore folder, if you use the SQL CE Toolbox DataConntext, you can use code like:

```
if (!db.DatabaseExists())
{
  db.CreateIfNotExists();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I found a problem. I wrote database initialization code here.

```
        public App()
        {
        // Show graphics profiling information while debugging.
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            db.create();
        }
```